# Videos do Youtube no site (só áudio)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, youtube

Estou precisando criar uma rádio para um cliente, onde ela irá ter como ele escolher o que tocar, por ritmos, cantor, banda, e etc.. Queria saber se há alguma forma de capturar playlists e videos do youtube para o site, mas para executá-los em áudio e não como video!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/ bons estudos

Answer (score 1):

Segundo os termos de serviço da [API do Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) você não pode:

> separar, isolar ou modificar os componentes de áudio ou vídeo de qualquer conteúdo audiovisual do YouTube disponibilizado por meio da API do YouTube;
>
> promover separadamente os componentes de áudio ou vídeo de qualquer conteúdo audiovisual do YouTube disponibilizado por meio da API do YouTube;